# gmessage{gWidgets} incorrect (?) behaviour

Tags: r, gwidgets

Here is the simplest possible example:

```
library(gWidgets)
gmessage("error test", icon="error")
gmessage("error test", icon="error")
```

If you choose tcltk as the gui toolkit the code works as expected, i.e. when the dialog appears clicking 'cancel' button dismisses the dialog and returns control back to your R session. But if you choose RGtk2, the second call to 'gmessage' does not produce any dialog or it is invisible, and as the 'gmessage' is a modal dialog, you lose control of your session.

If this is not a bug, please tell me what the correct way of calling 'gmessage' with RGtk2. Thank you.

P.S. There is a reason I don't provide parent/container as an argument. Just don't want to widen discussion.
P.P.S. I use R 2.14 (company decision) on openSuSE.

Comment: It is a bug, also present in `gWidgets2`, where I can hopefully fix it. Can you use that package instead? (Basically, the second dialog needs to be raised above the other windows, as it is buried under them.)

Comment: Looking into this, the issue is a lack of a parent. The dialog should sit above the parent, but may be covered by other windows. Without a window, even that isn't guaranteed. I'm not sure of a workaround to suggest. The things I tried I thought would work didn't. (I tested with `gWidgets2` which is where I would suggest you try out new things, as it is much easier for me to fix bugs -- if I can.)

Comment: @jverzani: Thank you for your suggestions. Thank you for the package and thank you for the book :) I will figure out something. It is just that 'gmessage' pops up in the center of the screen, while if I have to supply a container I have to be in charge of centering it and, unfortunately, I can't understand/find a simple way of doing it. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't the dialog center over the parent when you pass a `parent` argument? Anyways, for the dialogs it is a bit annoying, as you can't really manipulate the underlying Gtk object to get what you want, as the dialogs are modal. If you want, you could use the underlying `GDialog` class to do something though, as you can manipulate the object before calling `run`.